# Iteration through multiple sheet of excel in java

Tags: java, excel, loops, apache-poi

I am very new to java. I am creating pList from excel. My excel file contains multiple sheets. I want to iterate through all the sheets of the excel file. How to to this? please help.

Comment: What are you using to read/write Excel files? Apache POI?

Comment: Did you read the Apache POI docs??

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
public static void main( String [] args ) {
    try {

        InputStream input = POIExample.class.getResourceAsStream( "qa.xls" );
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);


        for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);

            // Do your stuff        
        }

    } catch ( IOException ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [apache poi documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#sheetIterator()) we see there is also an iterator available, which is in my opinion a cleaner solution:

```
Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.iterator();
while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
    Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
}
```

Depending on the type of workbook you use (HSSF or XSSF) you might need to execute an additional cast operation:

- HSSF: POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel '97(-2007) file format.

  ```
  HSSFSheet sheet = (HSSFSheet) sheetIterator.next();
  ```
- XSSF: POI Project's pure Java implementation of the Excel 2007 OOXML (.xlsx) file format.

  ```
  XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) sheetIterator.next();
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Java:

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator;
sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();
while(sheetIterator.hasNext()){
    Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
    out.println(sheet.getSheetName());
}
```

Scala:

`var iterator = workbook.sheetIterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext){
    var sheet = iterator.next
    println(sheet)
  }`